# Existence of a simple submodule

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ be a local ring and $N$ be a $R-$module such that every element of $N$ is killed by a power of $\mathfrak{m}$. Show that $N$ has at least a simple submodule, that is
$$soc(N)\ne0.$$

This implies a question : When does a $R-$module $N$ have simple submodule? ( Let $R$ be a commutative unitary ring that need not local)

Can you help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $R$ be a commutative unitary ring that need not be local.
Let $N$ be a nonzero $R$-module.

Suppose there exists a nonzero element $x$ of $N$ and a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $R$ such that $x$ is killed by a power of $\mathfrak{m}$.
Let $I$ be ann$(x)$.
Then $Rx$ is isomorphic to $R/I$.
By the assumption, there exists an integer $n > 0$ such that $\mathfrak{m}^n \subset I$.
We can assume that $n$ is the least such integer.
There exists $a \in \mathfrak{m}^{n-1} - I$.
Since $\mathfrak{m}a \subset \mathfrak{m}^n \subset I$, ann($a$ mod $I) = \mathfrak{m}$.
Hence $R/I$ contains a submodule isomorphic to $R/\mathfrak{m}$.
Hence $Rx$ contains a simple submodule.

Conversely suppose $N$ has a simple submodule $L$.
$L$ is of the form $Rx$, where $x$ is a nonzero element of $N$.
Let $\mathfrak{m}$ be ann($x$).
Since $L$ is isomorphic to $R/\mathfrak{m}$, $\mathfrak{m}$ is maximal.
Clearly $\mathfrak{m}x = 0$.

Comment: @ Makoto Kato: Perfect. $\mathfrak{m}^n\subset I\subset \mathfrak{m}$ implies $R/I$ is artinian, hence has a minimal ideal. How do you think about the last question?

Comment: @tlquyen Since $R$ may not be Noetherian, $R/I$ may not be Artinian. I did not assume that $R$ is a local ring. So I answered your last question.

Comment: I will show that $R/I$ is artinian if $\mathfrak{m}^n\subset I$.

Comment: I actually proved that $R/I$ is artinian although $R$ may not be noetherian. Do I have a confusion somewhere?

Comment: @tlquyen Let $k$ be a field.
Let $R = k[x_1,x_2,\dots]$ be the polynomial ring with infinitely many indeterminates.
Let $\mathfrak{m} = (x_1,x_2,\dots)$.
Since $R/\mathfrak{m}$ is isomorphic to $k$, $\mathfrak{m}$ is maximal.
Since $x_1$ (mod $\mathfrak{m}^2), x_2$ (mod $\mathfrak{m}^2), \dots$ are linearly independent over $k$,
dim$_k \mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2 = \infty$.
Hence $R/\mathfrak{m}^2$ is not artinian.

Comment: I have just found an interested case. Let $R$ be a local ring and $M$ is a finite $R-$module. Then, $M$ has a simple submodule iff for each maximal submodule $U$ of $M$, we always have $$\mbox{Ass}(M)=\mbox{Ass}(U)\cup\mbox{Ass}(M/U)$$.

Comment: Thank you. There is something wrong in my argument above. I will try to find it.